# Surjective morphism; if $U$ contains Kernel then $[G: U]=[H: \varphi[U]]$

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

> **Theorem.** Let $\varphi: G \rightarrow H$ be a surjective homomorphism (epimorphism) of the groups $G$ and $H$. $\varphi$ provides a bijection of the set of subgroups $U$ of $G$ with $\operatorname{ker}\varphi \subseteq U$ onto the set of subgroups of $H$ that preserves subgroup inclusion. The following applies to a subgroup $U$ of $G$ with $\operatorname{ker}\varphi \leq U$: It holds that $[G: U]=[H: \varphi[U]]$.

I proved that $U\leq G$ implies $\varphi[U]\leq H$. I am left with showing that $[G: U]=[H: \varphi[U]]$. A hint is:

> Show that for  $a, b \in G$
> $$
> a b^{-1} \in U \Leftrightarrow \varphi(a) \varphi(b)^{-1} \in \varphi[U].
> $$

One way is easy:
$$
\varphi(ab^{-1})=\varphi(a)\varphi(b^{-1})=\varphi(a)\varphi(b)^{-1}\in \varphi[U].
 $$
but I dont get the other one and I do not get how the statement follows.

Comment: $Ux\neq Uy$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\varphi(U)\varphi(x)\neq \varphi(U)\varphi(y)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First lets prove that if $\varphi(a)\varphi(b)^{-1}\in \varphi(U)$, then $ab^{-1}\in U$.

Let $a$ and $b$ be elements of $G$ such that $\varphi(a)\varphi(b)^{-1}\in\varphi(U)$. Then $\varphi(ab^{-1})\in\varphi(U)$, so there exists $x\in U$ such that $\varphi(x)=\varphi(ab^{-1})$. That means that $(ab^{-1})x^{-1}\in\ker(\varphi)$. But we are assuming that $\ker(\varphi)\leq U$, so this means $(ab^{-1})x^{-1}\in U$. Since $x\in U$, it follows that $ab^{-1}\in U$, as desired.

Now, in light of this equivalence, why are the indices the same? We show there is a bijection between the cosets of $U$ in $G$ and the cosets of $\varphi(U)$ in $\varphi(G)=H$. Define the map that sends the coset $Ua$ to the coset $U\varphi(a)$. This map is well defined and one-to-one, since:
$$\begin{align*}
Ua=Ub&\iff ab^{-1}\in U\\
&\iff \varphi(a)\varphi(b)^{-1}\in\varphi(U)\\
&\iff \varphi(U)\varphi(a) = \varphi(U)\varphi(b)\end{align*}$$
And this assignment is surjective: given a coset $\varphi(U)h$, there exists $a\in G$ such that $\varphi(a)=h$, so $Ua$ maps to $\varphi(U)h$.

Thus, we have established a bijection between cosets of $U$ in $G$ and cosets of $\varphi(U)$ in $H$, proving that $[G:U]=[H:\varphi(U)]$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin $aU=bU\ \Leftrightarrow\ b^{-1}a\in U$.

Comment: @kabenyuk Of course. Operating on minimal sleep and I usually use left cosets. Fixed.